# Get the More QuickTag button back

Tags: tinymce, read-more, plugin-tinymce, quicktag

I can't work out how to add the WP quicktag button back into the editor, I have customized the editor as below:

```
function gimko_format_tiny_mce($in) {
    $in['remove_linebreaks']=false;
    $in['convert_newlines_to_brs']=false;
    $in['keep_styles']=true;
    $in['tabfocus_elements']='major-publishing-actions';
    $in['paste_remove_styles']=false;
    $in['paste_remove_spans']=false;
    $in['paste_strip_class_attributes']='none';
    $in['paste_text_use_dialog']=true;
    $in['plugins']='inlinepopups,tabfocus,paste,media,fullscreen,wordpress,wpeditimage,wpgallery,wplink,wpdialogs,wpfullscreen';
    $in['apply_source_formatting']=false;
    $in['theme_advanced_buttons1']='formatselect,forecolor,|,bold,italic,underline,|,bullist,numlist,blockquote,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,link,unlink,|,wp_fullscreen,wp_adv';
    $in['theme_advanced_buttons2']='pastetext,pasteword,removeformat,|,charmap,|,outdent,indent,|,undo,redo';
    $in['theme_advanced_buttons3']='';
    $in['theme_advanced_buttons4']='';
    $in['valid_children'] = '+div[p]';
    return $in;
}
```

What do I need to add in to get it back showing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why this was so hard to answer, but after more research & playing around I have found the answer - for anyone else that is wondering, you just use `wp_more` in any of the `theme_advanced_buttons` indices.